# Gulp Watch seems to not working correctly. It sees the modifies, but doesn't build them

Tags: gulp, semantic-ui, gulp-watch

I've just downloaded the last release of [semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/), everything seems to work fine, but when I launch

```
gulp watch
```

and try to change a file, here what happen:

```
[gulp] Modified: src/site/globals/site.variables
```

And nothing happen ( no rebuild ). What could the problem be?

Comment: It return this message on any file you change?

Comment: from what folder are you running `gulp watch`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The problem is that there's a regex which creates the path to the proper files to modify and it fails.

What helped me:

1. Go to tasks/config/project/tasks.js
2. Replace `theme: /.*\/themes\/.*?(?=\/)/mg` to with `theme: /.*\\themes\\.*?(?=\\)/mg`
3. Run gulp watch again